# Submitting iOS app to app store application identifier invalid

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I'm using xcode 5 and I guess I'm missing where to change the bundle identifier.

When I try to validate my app for submission to the app store, I get two errors....

> Invalid code signing entitlements. Your application bundle's signature
>   contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS.
>   Speicifically value 'K8TE8KDZ95.com.iclinical.child' for key
>   'application-identifier' in 'Payload/iResus.app/iResus' is not
>   supported. This value should be a string starting with your TEAMID,
>   followed by a dot '.' followed by the bundle identifier

and

> The executable at Payload/iResus.app/iResus in Payload/iResus.app has
>   been signed with identifier 'com.iclinical.child' which does not match
>   the bundle identifier 'com.iclinical.childresus

I'm not sure where I should be changing this. The bundle identifier in the target is com.iclinical.child but clearly I need to change it somewhere else too....

Hope you can help.

Comment: maybe in your `info.plist` file?

Answer (score 73):

I just had both these error messages and here is how I fixed it:

1. Went into iTunes Connect > viewed my app (under manage apps) and copied the 'Bundle ID'
2. Went into xcode and pasted the 'Bundle ID' into the info.plist 'Bundle identifier' field
3. Restarted xcode
4. Xcode > Window > Organizer > Projects > 'Delete' derived data file for project
5. Xcode > Product > Alt + Clean (to Clean Build folder)

I then tried resubmitting and it all went through correctly.  I am 95% sure my Bundle ID was correct to begin with so it might have been something in steps 2 to 5 that fixed this.

Anyways hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Came across the same problem, searched in google, followed these steps and it worked... then realised it was from a post I added half a year ago. lol.

Comment: Thank you, i have almost same problem : "Specifically, value 'development for key 'aps-environment' in 'Paylaod/*********.app*/*********' is not supported."
After Clean Build Folder and Delete derived data file for project, it's works for me :)

Comment: Oh man you are awesome, this is a Bug in the xcode, @tessad Please mark as answer.

Answer (score 4):

In XCode 9, Open the Project Navigator, Select your target, check the following two places：

1. **General ---> Identity ---> Bundle Identifier**
2. **Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product bundle identifier**

Sometimes this issue happens when you have changed the Bundle Identifier in place 1， but place 2 did not change accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much, was exactly my problem

Answer (score 3):

I had the same errors trying to validate an app that was originally developed with a different bundle identifier than what I had entered into itunesconnect.

There were two issues that I came across:

1. If you change the bundle-identifier in XCode (General tab, Info tab or Info.plist), XCode won't archive the app with the new bundle identifier (in some cases) until you restart XCode.
2. If XCode is managing your provisioning profiles dynamically (normally using a wildcard bundle-identifier) and you are trying to use a fixed bundle identifier, you have to choose the static provisioning profile in your build settings.

I was surprised by the second issue because I never used XCode with a fixed provisioning profile and never had to download a profile in the past.

Since I wanted my app to use a wildcard bundle identifier, I changed it in itunesconnect and updated my settings, restarted XCode and my app validated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it works. I renamed my trial bundle to bundlePro and faced with this problem. Restart, alt+clean helps.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error, although I already submitted the app with this BundleID multiple times.

What solved the problem: performed Product->Clean and restarted Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm using xcode 5 and I guess I'm missing where to change the bundle identifier.*

In Xcode 5:

1. Open the Project Navigator
2. Select your project name at the top of the tree on the left
3. Single Click directly onto the project name (it should become
   highlighted)
4. Change the project name (the bundle id will be updated)
5. Once you highlight the blue project icon at the top of your project
   navigator you will have several tabs on the right hand side appear.
   Your bundle identifier should have the default value as noted below:

   com.company.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}

You might also want to create a sample empty project and note the project info defaults compared to your current settings.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The appID in the Apple developer portal (and the assigned to it distribution provisioning profile) is not the same as the bundle id in your project. You should change one of them. They should match in order to upload the app in the app store.

Comment: But it seems that your bundle identifier is com.iclinical.childresus and not com.iclinical.child

Answer (score 0):

How I resolved this:

1. Cleaned the build folder. Menu -> Product -> Alt key: Clean build folder.
2. Closed the XCode.
3. Deleted derived data.
4. Restarted my system. (Had to try this because steps 1 to 3 did not work for me as suggested in other posts).

After this created an app archive and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is incredibly dumb, but I had the exact same issue when working on two open projects at once in Xcode 11. The apparent solution was to quit and restart Xcode. I suspect there is some sort of Xcode bug or failure to context switch.