# Xcode 5 "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements" error

Tags: ios, xcode5

I want to release my app and I'm having a problem when trying to validate my app archive.

1. Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value `**********.com.DevName.YConvert` for key `application-identifier` in `Payload/YConvert+.app/YConvert+` is not supported. This value should be a string with your `TEAMID`, followed by a dot `.`, followed by the bundle identifier.
2. The executable at `Payload/YConvert+.app/YConvery+ i Payload/YConvert` does not match the bundle identifier `com.DevName.YConvert-`.
3. `CFBundleExecutable` in the `info.plist` file, may not contain any of those characters: `\ [] {} () .+*`

I am using Xcode 5 on OS X 10.9
Please Help!

Comment: This problem only occurs with xcode 5. The solution is to delete the developer profile and create a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across the exact same error.  Hope this step by step explanation helps:
[Submitting iOS app to app store application identifier invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120128/submitting-ios-app-to-app-store-application-identifier-invalid/20622401#20622401)