# Can't submit app to AppStore. "Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, submission

I'm trying to submit my app to the AppStore but all in vain. No matter what I do I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I tried cleaning, deleting derived data, restarting Xcode, restarting my Mac. Nothing helps. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120128/submitting-ios-app-to-app-store-application-identifier-invalid/20622401#20622401) suggests copying bundle from iTunesConnect and pasting it into the project, but it's not possible since iTunesConnect has changed and you are no longer able to copy bundle id from there. Any ideas, guys?

Comment: did you use Google Plus Framework in your app?

Comment: then just remove only one file 'GooglePlus.bundle' and check your app work? It's work for me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem existed because `Associated domains` and `iCloud` options (which wasn't actually required) were enabled for the app in the developer account. As soon as I disabled these options (and created new provisioning profile) the problem was gone

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using an wildcard prvisioning profile for upload the app just check the Provision profile

Comment: then recheck your bundle id. i think when you upload it it takes * provision.. You clear your build folder and reset your provision

Comment: my bundle id is ok. why would it take * provision?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, but i fixed it.

#### Solution 1

- Step 1: Show pack content, copy all files from the GooglePlus.bundle and paste theme into a new temp folder.
- Step 2: Add this new folder to the project.

#### Solution 2. (Optional, but put all old bundle file to the new bundler, and resign it)

- Step 1: Same as step 1 of solution 1
- Step 2: Create new target, with OS X/ Framework & Library / Bundle.
- Step 3: Right click on new target and add all file on the temp folder into this target.

See more: [Create new bundler](http://jaym2503.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-create-resource-bundle-in-ios.html)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue because I had selected the "Associated Domains" entitlement (on the Apple Developer site) however in Xcode 6.1.1 seemed to not allow an app to be submitted if you have the Associated Domains switch as off in the capabilities Xcode view.

You can therefore solve the Associated Domain issue by going to your app target in Xcode, Capabilities, Associated Domains and hitting the switch to ON if it's off. You don't have to add any info/domains but it seems to make Xcode happy!

See image below:
[image]

Alternatively if you can (and don't mind) then you could remove the Associated Domain entitlement when configuring your app on the Apple Developer site and re-download the certs/profiles.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't use G+, you can remove Google's bundle from app's Frameworks.