# Bundle validation error when including the Google+ SDK in my iOS app

Tags: ios, google-plus, code-signing

I'm trying to submit my app with the Google+ SDK on board. I'm getting the following error all the time:

> Error ITMS-9000 the bundle is invalid. your application bundle's signature  contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS 
>   Specifically, value **********.com.example.test for key
>   application-identifier in
>   '`Payload/*****.app/GooglePlus.bundle/GPPSignin3Resource`' is not
>   supported. This value should be a string with your TEAMID, followed by
>   a dot ., followed by the bundle identifier.

Also, I see the same error for `GPPCommonShareResources` and for `GPPShareboxSharedResources`. I've already tried to clean my project, relaunch Xcode, etc., but that doesn't help.

I'm sure that bundle ID of my app is the same, like Xcode's asking for. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same problem here, it worked a few days ago.

Comment: Please add google-plus tag to your question so it gets attention from g+ team.

Comment: The bug report has been posted: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=972&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? From [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=972&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) it looks like the update to SDK version 1.7.1 has solved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove files in GooglePlus.bundle in your finder:

```
GooglePlus.bundle/GPPSignIn3PResources
GooglePlus.bundle/GPPCommonSharedResources.bundle/GPPCommonSharedResources
GooglePlus.bundle/GPPShareboxSharedResources.bundle/GPPShareboxSharedResources
```

and clear project

---Edit----

upgrade new SDK v1.7.1

Comment: Did that, but then naturally i lost all g+ funcionality.

Comment: using g + app or the browser?

Comment: If you do this, app will crash when you'll try to share something.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting the derived data file as mentioned in #4 of the answer to this post:
[Submitting iOS app to app store application identifier invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120128/submitting-ios-app-to-app-store-application-identifier-invalid/20622401#20622401) :

> 1. Went into iTunes Connect > viewed my app (under manage apps) and copied the 'Bundle ID'
> 2. Went into xcode and pasted the 'Bundle ID' into the info.plist 'Bundle identifier' field
> 3. Restarted xcode
> 4. Xcode > Window > Organizer > Projects > 'Delete' derived data file for project
> 5. Xcode > Product > Alt + Clean (to Clean Build folder)

Comment: Doesnt work for me too. I also updated g+ ios sdk to the latest version.