# How to set Bundle Identifier correctly in Xcode 6.1.1 when I am using external charts in C-Objective?

Tags: ios, xcode, external, bundle-identifier

I have an iPad application made in Xcode 6.1.1 in which I am using external chart in C-Objective. Everything is working perfectly until I set up Bundle Identifier.

If I want to test it (without error) in simulator I need to have Bundle identifiers to all my parts set like:

```
Main part...com.Project
Other part...com.Project.SomePart
Chart....com.Project.Chart
```

Etc.

But in this case if I want to Archive it (for ITunes registering purposes) with this set up there is error:

```
*"The provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“PROFILE”) has an AppID of “com.Project” which does not match your bundle identifier “com.Project.Chart”.  Xcode can resolve this issue by downloading a new provisioning profile from the Member Center."*
```

This error disappear and I am free to archive when a set up my Bundle identifiers like this:

```
Main part...com.Project
Other part...com.Project.SomePart
**Chart....com.Project**
```

Etc.

But in this case I can't test it in simulator because of error error:

```
*An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)*
```

Which I found out is because of prefixes.

How should I continue if I want to get my app online at iTunes? Is it key that I can't test it in that configuration which Archive(and validation and submitting) takes?

Comment: It means your developer account doesn't have the app registered or it has your  app registered with another bundle identifier.

Comment: see this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120128/submitting-ios-app-to-app-store-application-identifier-invalid

Comment: I do have it registered for Bundle com.Project...the rest of it is just part of this one app. Problem is with that external chart I use

Comment: (chart is part of the app and i have to set bundle identification to that as I write before) problem is that Archive process wants to connect it with profile and main Bundle id...it just does not take it as part of the app.... and unfortunately non of those answers to that other question fits for me

Answer (score 0):

Correct setting of Bundle ID is the usual one with prefix of Bundle ID and with the sufix with dot

BundleID.sufix

The problem was that at my developer account I wrongly created Explicit App ID and it was suppose to be Wildcard App ID because of framework I used.